# Logic help in displaying unique reviews in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

Basically, I have a web application that have a module that displays reviews and ratings. Data areis retrieved from firebaseFirebase and i storedI store them in an array of objects (please see photo below).

So my problem is that i want to display each reviewee's name as only one, so example there are instances that a certain reviewee will be reviewed by many reviewers, so in my array , if a certain reviewee is reviewed by many reviewers, his/her name will be existing a lot of times in a row of array of objects. so i

I wanted to display a certain revieweereviewee that is reviewed by many reviewers many timetimes, once only. howHow do i do that? iI mean can someone give me a logic/constraints on how iI will implement it and ill be the one to code it.?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Can you please show the desired output? I'm really trying to understand what you want to accomplish, but it's being quite hard to properly understand, the middle part of your question is confusing.

Comment: hi briosheje. sorry about the inconvenience. So, i inserted some pictures above and thats what im trying to achieve. please forgive me for the bad design tho

Comment: You need to be much more specific. Add the code of your attempt, as this is not a code writing service. Provide the data structure in text format (use the  `{}` button in the editor to format it as code), not as an image. Pinpoint *where* in your code you bump into an issue, what the expected output is (in HTML format, not only an image), and what you get instead. NB: fix the obvious spelling mistakes (areis? revieweereviewee? timetimes?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for.

```js
var data = [{"RevieweeName":"Vignesh","ReviewerName":"A",content:"good",rating:1},
                    {"RevieweeName":"Vignesh","ReviewerName":"B",content:"Bad",rating:2},
                    {"RevieweeName":"Vignesh","ReviewerName":"B",content:"so good",rating:4},
                    {"RevieweeName":"Kavin","ReviewerName":"A",content:"good",rating:1},
                    {"RevieweeName":"Raja","ReviewerName":"C",content:"bad",rating:3},
                    {"RevieweeName":"Gokul","ReviewerName":"A",content:"very bad",rating:2},
                    {"RevieweeName":"Raja","ReviewerName":"C",content:"good",rating:5},
                    {"RevieweeName":"Kavin","ReviewerName":"C",content:"bad",rating:5}];
        var result = {};
        
        for(var index in data)
        {
            var obj = data[index];
            result[obj.RevieweeName] = result[obj.RevieweeName] || {ratings:[],comments:[]}
            var resultobj = result[obj.RevieweeName];
            resultobj.ratings.push(obj.rating);
            var commentobj = {}; commentobj[obj.ReviewerName] = obj.content;
            resultobj.comments.push(commentobj);
        }
        
        for(var index in result)
        {
            var obj = result[index], total=0;
            for(var i in obj.ratings) { total += obj.ratings[i]; }
            obj.avgrating = Math.floor((total/obj.ratings.length)*100)/100;
        }
        
        console.log(result);
```

Comment: OMG didint expect this. Its been days already finding the best and most efficient way of doing this. Thank you very much vignesh raja. im trying my best to understand every line of code you wrote but i didn't understand some hehe.

Comment: having a hard time displaying a certain element in console hehehe.

Comment: Are you still facing any issues ?

Comment: as of the moment, im trying my best to understand your code, printing in console what a certain line of code does because im just a beginner and it is really written professionally. hoping to be like you one day  hands down to you vignesh raja.

Comment: can i ask what does this code does?
result[obj.RevieweeName] = result[obj.RevieweeName] || {ratings:[],comments:[]} initiates?

Comment: Actually I am iterating over the array of objects and splitting it into the format you specified and put them in the result object with reviewee name as key.
If same person is reviewed by different persons, then we will have two objects (See first 2 obj in arr). In result obj, if I have the details related the reviewee already then it will be got or else it will assigned a new value.
Ex: `var a = {name:"vignesh"}; a.name = a.name || "raja".` Here value dont change. But here `var a = {}; a.name = a.name || "raja".` Since `a.name` is `undefined`, `raja` will be set as value

Comment: can i ask one last question sir? how do i display a certain reviewee name from array results? what if i want to display vignesh and all the comments he/she has? im trying every possible way i know but i am always getting undefined. :((

Comment: Looks like you are very very beginner. I can see me in you as some years back. :P

Comment: `for(var key in results){console.log(key, results[key])}`

Comment: yeah. Im so sorry about that sir. im new to javascript technology hehehe.

Comment: now i understand. never thought you can use strings as key in arrays hehehe. can i ask one last one last question sir.  
for(var key in result)
        {
            console.log(key, result[key].comments);
             for(var key in result[key].comments){
                console.log("comments");
             }
        }

Comment: so for displaying comments i structured a nested loop but how do i print a comment? console.log("comments" ?) whats the parameter?

Comment: Replace it by `console.log(key,result[key].comments[key])` - 1. Commentator name 2. Comment

Comment: it gives me, typeError: cannot read property 'Vignesh' of undefined

Comment: `for(var key in result) {
          for(var key2 in result[key].comments){ 
          console.log(key2, result[key].comments[key2]);
        } }`

Comment: oh i used the same var name in both for loops. sorry about that

Comment: Thank you very much vignesh raja. I learned alot from you. Thank you for accomodating me really thank you. hands down on how efficient you wrote code.

Comment: You may need to take basic examples to learn to work on the js to learn basic.These are huge dude.

Comment: yes i will :). was new to nested array? if thats what you call that hehe. any  more tips sir vignesh ?

Comment: No need if you dont want. Thought of having a friend outside India. :P